# Is it possible to determine the managed pipeline IIS7 is running under in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, managed, pipeline

Is it possible to determine the managed pipeline IIS7 is running under in ASP.NET?

Comment: Did you mean ASP.NET under IIS7?

Comment: Yes, that's it and the answer is below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean the integrated pipeline mode?  If so then you're looking for: [`HttpRuntime.UsingIntegratedPipeline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.usingintegratedpipeline.aspx?ppud=4).

```
if(HttpRuntime.UsingIntegratedPipeline) {
  //Yep we're using it
}
```